# Change UIMenu title with multiple line (UIMenu with UIButton)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uimenu

I added UIMenu to the UIButton.menu with long title, but menu show not full text. **Is there anyway to change it to show full text** ? thanks for help

```
 let _: [()] = (0...100).map {
            childdrens.append(UIAction(title: "This is a very very very very very very very very very long title \($0)", handler: {  _ in
            }))
        }
  longCapMenuButton = UIMenu(title: "", options: .displayInline, children: childdrens ) 
  longCapMenuButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
```

**Screenshot Attached below-**

[image]

Comment: As per the user's interaction, the menu is designed for a short label name.

Comment: well in some cases users want to look a long titles, so I want to find a way to display them without uisng 3rd party